# containsKey() allways returns true

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I want to compare two self created Objects, but the containsKey() allways returns `true`.

The Map structure is :

```
Map<MethodReport,List<MethodReport>> calledMap
```

Here is my `MethodReport` class:

```
public class MethodReport {
    private String nombre;
    private String paquete;
    private int LOC;
    private String resultado;
    private int lineaClase;
    private String tipo;

    public MethodReport() {

    }

    public MethodReport(String nombre, String paquete, int lOC, String resultado, int lineaClase, String tipo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.paquete = paquete;
        LOC = lOC;
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.lineaClase = lineaClase;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public MethodReport(String nombre) {
        nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MethodReport)) {
            return false;
        }
        MethodReport m = (MethodReport) obj;
        return this.nombre.equals(m.getNombre());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.nombre);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.paquete+this.nombre;
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is in the `hashCode()` and `equals` . Thank you so much.

Comment: Your single-arg constructor is wrong, it doesn't set `this.nombre`.

Answer (score 2):

Assign `nombre` to the field variable of the same name rather than to itself in the single argument constructor

```
this.nombre = nombre;
```